# Intergrating Firebase Phone authentication and Django Backend

Tags: django, firebase, flutter, django-rest-framework, firebase-authentication

I have created a Django backend for my flutter app. I have used the Django rest framework to connect two. Now for user authentication, I am using firebase on my flutter application. It's working fine.

Now since the user management is done by firebase, how can I add a user to my Django backend when the user signup through my app to firebase. I want firebase to handle the signup/sign-in process but also want to create a user profile on my Django server which contains information about the user's address, profile pic, orders, payment history etc.

Also, I want Django to know if the user is authenticated with firebase while calling API requests. How can I make Django handle such requests?

Comment: I think you can use cloud functions. When an authentication is done in firebase this can trigger your function and add it your backend. If I am not wrong you can check the status of auth in your app code. If the status ok about auth, you can simply add the user to your backend I hope.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the reply. Yes, the check can be done whether the user is logged in or not in app, but to create a user on Django, it requires the user's password. I am trying to make user login with just OTP 

The user could log in with OTP but in the API request to Django, I could not figure out how to send authentication detail and make Django know the user is authenticated cause, the authentication token is provided by the firebase. 
In other way, i want to add User on django with username and phonenumber, and it could somehow verify that user is authenticated by the firebase token.